# how to list up visited file-line locations while browsing with vim?

Tags: vim, ctags

I think I knew this but forgot. I tried `:ts` or `g]` but it doesn't work as I want.

Many times I use vim to analyze source codes. I use `gf` (when cursor is in a file name, if I press `gf`, the editor opens the file), or `g]` or `ctrl-t` a lot. (with tags file generated by ctags, when cursor is on a variable or type name, pressing `g]` jumps to that location, letting me select from candidates when there are many candidates, and `ctrl-t` makes me go back.)

After many such operations, sometimes I want to go back to a specific `{file,line_number}` location that I recently visited. (`gi`, `go` incrementally goes forward or backward).

I forgot, but for this purpose, there is a command to list up the locations showing the locations, my current location shown in the middle so I can choose from +3 or -2 (0 is my current location). What is that command?  (Just doing `:rew` goes to the first file.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (`gi`, `go` incrementally goes forward or backward)

`gi` and `go` don't do that. You must be thinking about `<C-i>` and `<C-o>`, which get you through the "jump list".

The command you are looking for is `:jumps` and it is documented under `:help jump-motions`, like `<C-i>` and `<C-o>`.

> (Just doing `:rew` goes to the first file.)

Indeed, the argument list and the jump list are totally unrelated.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. When I retried it,  ctrl-o, ctrl-i is the command I want. and :jumps was the list-up command.